# Using external hard drive/USB stick to transfer files

Tags: usb, hard-drive, hp, mac, compatibility

I know very little about computers generally and am new to Ubuntu, so I'm looking for an answer that an idiot can understand!

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a fairly old HP laptop (EliteBook 2560p). I installed the OS successfully from a USB drive, following the instructions online, and it's now installed on the computer's own hard drive.

I also have a 2011 MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. All I want to do is transfer ordinary files (music, videos, .docx, etc) from this MacBook to the laptop running Ubuntu.

My large external hard drive (where I back up all my important files, and which works fine with my MacBook) does not appear to be recognized at all by the laptop with Ubuntu. The light on the hard drive doesn't even come on like it does when connected to my MacBook. The same is true of my little 16GB USB stick.

I have another little 4GB USB stick, which I used to initially boot and install Ubuntu onto the HP laptop. This USB stick is still formatted according to the instructions on how to boot Ubuntu from an external hard drive. It's recognized by my computer running Ubuntu, and I can view its contents in the Files app, but I appear to be unable to delete them here, or to delete any partitions in the Disks app. When I insert this USB stick into my MacBook, I get a message telling me "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer", with the options to "Initialize...", "Ignore" or "Eject". If I click on "Initialize...", I get taken to Disk Utility, where the drive is visible and I appear to be able to clear and reformat it (although I haven't tried yet).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to transfer the files currently on my big external hard drive onto my HP-Ubuntu laptop *without first removing them from the drive and putting them back on*. If that's not possible, I'd like to clear and reformat the two little USB sticks so that I can use them to transfer files back and forth between the two computers.